# Problema al realizar un registro multiple con PHP en una base de datos en MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, aplicación-web

Hola a todos colegas estoy desarrollando un proyecto para mi universidad y tengo que realizar un formulario en el cual se encuentra los inputs para realizar el registro de etapas de un proyecto las cuales son 14 y deben de ser almacenadas todas de una sola vez al presionar el boton de enviar

Tengo un formulario el cual lo realizo a través de un ciclo *for* el cual el cual el código es el siguiente:

```html
<div class="container p-1">
<form action="guardarvisitantes.php" method="POST">
        <p></p>
        <div class="col-md-16">
        <input id="title" name="title" placeholder="Nombre del proyecto" type="text" required="required" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <p></p>

<div class="col-md-16">
                <table class="table table-striped table-sm table-borderless">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Etapa</th>
                            <th>Responsable</th>
                            <th>Fecha de Entrega Esperada</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                             <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 14; $i++) { ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <select class="form-control" name="combobox[]">
                                            <option>---Selecciona Etapa---</option>
                                            <option>Junta Inicial</option>
                                            <option>Instalación</option>
                                            <option>Layout</option>
                                            <option>Turnos - Horarios</option>
                                            <option>Periodos - Catalogos</option>
                                            <option>Uso del lector</option>
                                            <option>instalación del lector</option>
                                            <option>Comunicación</option>
                                            <option>Reportes</option>
                                            <option>Desarrollo</option>
                                            <option>Exportación a nomina</option>
                                            <option>Capacitación final</option>
                                            <option>Perfiles de acceso</option>
                                            <option>Junta de entrega</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="Responsable[]" placeholder="Nombre del resposable"></td>
                                        <td><input type="date" class="form-control" id="date[]" placeholder="Password"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php } ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <button type="submit" name="guardarSub" class="btn btn-primary">Registrar Proyecto</button>
                </form>
        </div>
</div>
```

El cual se mira de la siguiente forma

[image: Formulario de registro múltiple]

a través de el botón envió por método POST los datos de cada input al archivo *guardarvisitantes.php* el cual es el siguiente:

```
<?php
////////////////// CONEXION A LA BASE DE DATOS //////////////////

$host = 'localhost';
$basededatos = 'php_crud_mysql';
$usuario = 'root';
$contraseña = 'ErikVanLeonard1';



$conexion = new mysqli($host, $usuario,$contraseña, $basededatos);
if ($conexion -> connect_errno) {
die( "Fallo la conexión : (" . $conexion -> mysqli_connect_errno() 
. ") " . $conexion -> mysqli_connect_error());
}




if(isset($_POST['guardarSub']))

                {

                $title = ($_POST['title']);
                $items1 = ($_POST['Responsable']);
                $items2 = ($_POST['date']);
                $items3 = ($_POST['date']);
                $items4 = ($_POST['combobox']);

                ///////////// SEPARAR VALORES DE ARRAYS, EN ESTE CASO SON 4 ARRAYS UNO POR CADA INPUT (ID, NOMBRE, CARRERA Y GRUPO////////////////////)
                while(true) {

                    //// RECUPERAR LOS VALORES DE LOS ARREGLOS ////////
                    $item1 = current($items1);
                    $item2 = current($items2);
                    $item3 = current($items3);
                    $item4 = current($items4);

                    ////// ASIGNARLOS A VARIABLES ///////////////////
                    $res=(( $item1 !== false) ? $item1 : ", &nbsp;");
                    $inicio=(( $item2 !== false) ? $item2 : ", &nbsp;");
                    $entrega=(( $item3 !== false) ? $item3 : ", &nbsp;");
                    $etapa=(( $item4 !== false) ? $item4 : ", &nbsp;");

                    //// CONCATENAR LOS VALORES EN ORDEN PARA SU FUTURA INSERCIÓN ////////
                    $valores='('.$etapa.',"'.$res.'","'.$inicio.'","'.$entrega.'","'.$title.'"),';

                    //////// YA QUE TERMINA CON COMA CADA FILA, SE RESTA CON LA FUNCIÓN SUBSTR EN LA ULTIMA FILA /////////////////////
                    $valoresQ= substr($valores, 0, -1);

                    ///////// QUERY DE INSERCIÓN ////////////////////////////
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO stages (description, days, date_entrega, person, project) 
                    VALUES $valoresQ";


                    $sqlRes=$conexion->query($sql) or mysqli_error();


                    // Up! Next Value
                    $item1 = next( $items1 );
                    $item2 = next( $items2 );
                    $item3 = next( $items3 );
                    $item4 = next( $items4 );

                    // Check terminator
                    if($item1 === false && $item2 === false && $item3 === false && $item3 === false) break;

                }

                }

            ?>
```

Al realizar el envió a través de submit obtengo el siguiente error

> ```
> Warning current() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given en la linea de codigo 34-36, 56 y 60-60
> ```

¿Cual podria ser el error y como podria solucionarl?

Comment: Debes asignar el atributo value a los options del select y tienes un error en escritura `<input type="text" class="form-control" name="responesable[]" placeholder="Nombre del resposable">` y en php esperas `Responsable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veo varios errores en tu códico Erik, pero solo 1 influye en lo demás.

Esta linea:

```
<td><input type="date" class="form-control" id="date[]" placeholder="Password"></td>
```

debería ser así

```
<td><input type="date" class="form-control" name="date[]" placeholder="Password"></td>
```

> Tenias `id="value"` en lugar de `name="value"`

Eso debería solucionar el error actual.

Para entrar en detalles y puedas entender lo que pasa por si te pasa algo parecido, el error dice que `current()` necesita 1 parametro de tipo Array, pero tu codigo `$item2 = current($items2);` y `$item3 = current($items3);`, las variables que pasas por parametros no son Arrays son NULL por causa de lo que te comenté.